# saving multiple tables at once in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have an action that update three tables at once like this:

```
    def action_save
        @user.update(param_param_list1)
        @application.update(param_list2)
        @college.update(param_list3)
    end
```

but to make the program better, I want to either save all three together at once or not at all

Comment: How is it determined whether to save them or not?

Comment: You can make a transaction ?

Answer (score 7):

Use an [`ActiveRecord::Transaction`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html):

```
def action_save
  @college.transaction do
    @user.update!(param_param_list1)
    @application.update!(param_list2)
    @college.update!(param_list3)
  end
end
```

A transaction ensures that all the database action within that block are performed. Or if there is an error, then the whole transaction is rolled back.